# Dart foreach vs for loop for async

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter application allows users to pick up files from device storage and upload to server.
Here is my code.

This is http request section

```
http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
request.headers.addAll(headers);
```

This is foreach loop section and output

```
files.forEach((element) async {
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'files', element.path!,
        //contentType: new MediaType('application', 'octet-stream'),
      ));
    });
kLog('$serviceLog >>> start requesting....');
kLog('$serviceLog >>> File Length : ${request.files.length}');
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
```

[image]

Foreach not getting the correct result although I use async and await keywords.

This is for loop section and output

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  request.files
      .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("files", files[i].path!));
}
kLog('$serviceLog >>> start requesting....');
kLog('$serviceLog >>> File Length : ${request.files.length}');
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
```

[image]

For loop is working without async keyword and the output correctly

Please enlighten me if there's something wrong with my codes

Comment: @SamChan, still same not getting result 5

    Future.forEach(files, (PlatformFile element) async {
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'files', element.path!
      ));
    });

Comment: What happen in case 1 is that `forEach` does not complete and it process to print function. To use `Future.forEach` should be like `await Future.forEach(list,element)...`. Do you use `await`

Comment: @SamChan.. Thanks bro. I need to use like 'await Future.forEach()'

Comment: Yes, would you mind to try it again?

Comment: @SamChan, It works bro. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome.